# Xamarin.Forms Display Text in ListView instead of typename

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I'm filling a Xamarin.Forms.ListView with items.

```
public class LCIDEditor : ContentPage
{
    private ListView _lv;
    private ObservableCollection<TextCell> _ItemList = new ObservableCollection<TextCell>();

    public LCIDEditor()
    {
        this.Title = "LCIDEditor";

        _ItemList.Add(new TextCell { Text = "Englisch", Detail = "1033" });
        _ItemList.Add(new TextCell { Text = "Deutsch", Detail = "1031" });

        _lv = new ListView();
        _lv.ItemsSource = _ItemList;
        _lv.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));

        this.Content = _lv;
    }
}
```

In the best case, I get the listview to display something like "Xamarin.Forms.TextCell" in the ListView instead of any real text.

If I include

```
_lv.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
```

, I see nothing at all, the listview stays blank.

Can somebody show me what I'm doing wrong here?
I read through the docs, but they're not helpful, and I saw other people asking the same question but with in other situations.

I'm trying to deal with this (obviously not so) simple example.

Comment: Remove the `TextCell` from your items's creation. Do just `_ItemList.Add(new { Text = "Englisch", Detail = "1033" });` and insert it after the ItemTemplate set command line.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Thanks, but it doesn't work this way for various reasons. Would you mind posting the entire code?

Comment: You're right, sorry. It's because of the `ObservableCollection<TextCell>`. It must be `ObservableCollection<object>`. I'll post the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
public class LCIDEditor : ContentPage
{
    private ListView _lv;
    private ObservableCollection<object> _ItemList = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    public LCIDEditor()
    {
        this.Title = "LCIDEditor";

        _ItemList.Add(new { Text = "Englisch", Detail = "1033" });
        _ItemList.Add(new { Text = "Deutsch", Detail = "1031" });

        _lv = new ListView() 
        {
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell)), 
            ItemsSource = _ItemList
        };

        this.Content = _lv;
    }
}
```

- The TextCell must be used like an template, not like item;
- When the DataTemplate's ViewCell is not bound or the object's type is not recognized as a valid item, it shows the `ToList()` result - the type name by default.

You should test the code, I didn't run it here.

I hope it work for you